# node server is not working

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, angular6

i am working on angular 6 and node js. While i  go to fetch data from database and run node server then at localhost:3000 page doesn't works  but when i run ng serve then it works on localhost:4200 but doesn't show data coming from database.

Comment: So, From what I could understand, your db data resides at some node REST service which can be consumed at `localhost:3000` and your angular app runs at `localhost:4200` right?

Comment: angular app is running on localhost:3000 too but showing only those pages that  i have made before i insert my fetching code.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons for that. I can say nothing until I see the code.
But some reasons for that might be 1. 3000 port is not listening to your node it may be busy
2. localhost:3000 spelling should be correct in the browser 3. problem might be in body parser when you use it incorrectly, you will be in trouble.
Hope you will fix it.

Comment: 3000 is listening , it  works when i print throw url but it does not when i print it on template. is it possible that angular  is not  working on 3000, it is working on 4200.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is running on 4200 port and node is running on 3000. Both are working on different servers. may be an issue of cross-domain. Implement CORS on Node, as it is receiving requests, this will solve your problem.

Comment: forgive me! but how to do that??